# How to work with DataBinder.Eval in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView contains Lables, I need to show/hide Lables based on data.

Here is my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Profiles" runat="server" CssClass="grid" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                        OnRowDataBound="GridView_Profiles_OnRowDataBound" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="90%">
    <Columns>
      <asp:Label ID="Label_SelectedCount" runat="server"> 
        <span style="width:auto;color:White;background-color:#0c95be;height:auto;margin:0px;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
          <%#Eval("Count") %>
        </span>
      </asp:Label>
     <asp:Label ID="lblNoCount" runat="server" Text="-"></asp:Label>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In the above GridView `RowDataBound` how should I check for the bounding data using `DataBinder.Eval`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get Label in RowDataBound event with `DataBinder.Eval`:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // find your label text in gridview with DataBinder.Eval
        string count = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Count") as string;

        // find your label control in gridview
        Label lb = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label_SelectedCount");

        // check condition to show/hide label (you use your own condition)
        if(count > 0)
            lb.Visible = true;
        else
            lb.Visible = false;

    }
}
```

Or you can bind GridView with `DataBinder.Eval` like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Count"
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label_SelectedCount" runat="server" >
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Count")%>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Note:** You can also bind data to Label's Text attribute like this `Text='<%#Eval("Count") %>'`.

Answer (score 0):

> I use ToString() becuase when data is not string I get "null"

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string count = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Count").ToString();
        
        Label LabelCount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label_SelectedCount");
        
        if((int)count > 0)
            LabelCount .Visible = true;
        else
            LabelCount .Visible = false;
    }
}
```